# how to retrieve and iterate values from a java bean using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi friends I dont have experience working with hashmap, I need to create 3 hashmap elements in a java class to retrieve and iterating the values coming from a java bean like this

```
private String value1;                  
private String value2;                  
private String value3;

public String getValue1() {
    return value1;
}
public void setValue1(String value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}
public String getValue2() {
    return value2;
}
public void setValue2(String value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}
public String getValue3() {
    return value3;
}
public void setValue3(String value3) {
    this.value3 = value3;
}
```

I need to sort each value in each hashmap

```
HashMap<String> values1 = new HashMap<String>();
HashMap<String> values2 = new HashMap<String>();
HashMap<String> values3 = new HashMap<String>();
```

Could you please help me?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect to come out?

Comment: Have you looked at the HashMap tutorial? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm

Answer (score 0):

A hash structure, usually desn't care about sorting. I am not say that is impossible, that it just not make that much sense create a hash structure where you have to spend CPU clocks with sorting operations.

Anyway, if you wanna to have a `Map` which is sorted, you can use a `TreeMap`, such a structure store the elements in a tree format using the key comparison to guarantee the correct order.

PS: By the way, a HashMap usually has a Key and a Value, If you wanna store just a String you should use a Set instead.